# How can I Magento 1.6.1 Product Image import from External Url

Tags: image, magento, import, product

I would like help on how I can import product images from external image location. am using magento 1.6.1

Comment: check this link [Mass Import Script](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32491/P195/#t255906)

Comment: Try using [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki) it will do this

Answer (score 0):

I do this directly in the Template. When i set the imagename like the Image at the other end.

I have a Image on an other server thats http://www.foo.com/foo/foo/bar.png

When i import my products i set the Image to /foo/foo/bar.png

In the Template I i set the link to

```
<img src="http://www.foo.com/<?php echo $_product->getFile(); ?>">
```

At this method you have no caching of images. In case of that the Shop runs a little bit slower.

Regards boti